# Processing - Simple Null Pointer Error

Tags: java, processing

I have created an array of custom objects in my processing code and then proceed to init it. However, for some reason I run into a null pointer exception at: `objectArray[i].siteID = 5;`

I have spent the last 2 hours trying to find info on how to fix this but the syntax *seems* to be correct!

Code:

```
class TtalkObject{
  int siteID = 0;
  String URL = "test";
  int commentNum = 5;
  int averageLength = 5;

}

PFont f;
TtalkObject[] objectArray;
int whatObjectPart = 0;
int whatObject = 0;

void setup()
{
    size(300,300);
    f=createFont("Arial",16,true);
    objectArray = new TtalkObject[50];

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i ++){
        objectArray[i].siteID = 5;
        objectArray[i].URL = "test";
        objectArray[i].commentNum = 10;
        objectArray[i].averageLength = 10; 
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your program in a debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're never creating an instance of your `TtalkObject`, you're just initializing an array to hold fifty of those objects.

I'm not familiar with java syntax, in c# it'd be

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i ++){
 objectArray[i] = new TtalkObject();
 objectArray[i].siteID = 5;
 objectArray[i].URL = "test";
 objectArray[i].commentNum = 10;
 objectArray[i].averageLength = 10;
}
```

Comment: Well i'm sorry for asking a question that would give me negative points but i'm new and frustrated... anyways, thank you very much for the answers everyone.

Comment: you don't have to sorry, everything is okey in the stackhouse ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
objectArray = new TtalkObject[50]; //you have initilized array of 50 reference
```

but it doesn't mean each 50 reference points to an object

you need to create object for each of them.

Make it

```
objectArray = new TtalkObject[50]; 
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i ++){
 objectArray[i] = new TtalkObject();// or some other preferred initialization
 objectArray[i].siteID = 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Null pointer error usually occurs when you use something that you have not allocated memory for or when you access some variable which is out of scope.

Comment: I dunno who the f did -1 but if they have got a little brain I answered correctly he didn't do  objectArray[i] = new TtalkObject(); and was trying to access it.... which in other words mean.... using something that you have not allocated memory for....

Answer (score 1):

Put following on line 22

```
objectArray[i] = new TtalkObject();
```